# Zip folders with Python is adding an extra folder

Tags: python-3.x, windows, zip, subdirectory

I can zip up a file with Python using:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("jam.zip", "w") as zippy:
  zippy.write('custard.txt')
```

to zip up a folder I can use:

```
myfolder = "D:\\temp\\myfolder"
thefiles = os.listdir(myfolder)
with zipfile.ZipFile("jam.zip", "w") as zippy:
  for file in thefiles:
    file_path = os.path.join(myfolder, file)
    zippy.write(file_path)
```

This works fine but creates a zip file like this:

```
 jam.zip
 .   temp
     .   myfolder
         .   custard.txt
```

It's zipped the correct files and folder, but has included "temp" as an extra extraneous folder.
How do I zip it so it's in this like this:

```
 jam.zip
 .   myfolder
     .   custard.txt
```

Comment: Try an `os.chdir("D:\\temp")` first, then `os.listdir("myfolder")`.

Comment: You mean `os.listdir(myfolder)` without quotes? Sadly that just creates the zip file (with the same structure) at D:\\temp

Comment: No, _with_ quotes, assuming that that's the actual name of the folder. If you like, do `myfolder="myfolder"`, and then without quotes is the same thing. Then your `filepath` construction can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pathlib.Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) to pass along the relative path as an argument for `arcname` of the method [`zipfile.ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write). This will remove the `temp` folder.

```py
import zipfile

from pathlib import Path

FOLDER = r"D:\temp\test"

FILE_DESTINATION = r"D:\temp\test.zip"

with zipfile.ZipFile(FILE_DESTINATION, "w") as archive:
    for path in Path(FOLDER).glob("**/*"):
        archive.write(path, path.relative_to(FOLDER))
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use [`shutil.make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) and passing along an argument for `root_folder`.

```py
import shutil

FOLDER = r"D:\temp\test"

# creates D:\temp\test.zip
shutil.make_archive(FOLDER, format="zip", root_dir=FOLDER)
```